# How to include custom polymer element inside another

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

How to include custom polymer 3 element inside another? 
Let's say I have two components:

1) Parent-component
2) Child-component

I would like to include and use child component inside parent component. The question is: where should I put my child element and how to configure import path?

Answer (score 1):

In your parent element add the import declaration of the child element:

`import './child-element.js';`

Then, add a reference of the imported element in the parent's template:

`<child-element></child-element>`

Your child element could be like:

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

class ChildElement extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }
      </style>
      <div>This is you child element</div>
    `;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('child-element', ChildElement);
```